# Combining two VBA codes together

Tags: excel, vba

Apologises if this is a silly question, but I am a novice at this.

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I just can't figure it out.

I want to be able to run the two VBA's at the same time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("J2:J40"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="PW"
    xRg.Locked = True
    Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="PW"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
xCellColumn = 10
xTimeColumn = 9
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

If the edited Cell is in column J (row 2 or higher), and Target contains only one Cell

- Unprotect sheet
- If the cell is not empty

  - Stop Excel from processing all other events (editing other cells)
  - Add the Date-Time stamp in Cell column I, same row as edited cell
  - Start processing events again
- Lock edited cell (Target)
- Protect sheet again

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const PW = "PW"

    With Target
        If .Column = 10 And .Row > 1 And .CountLarge = 1 Then   'J2:J(lastRow)
            .Worksheet.Unprotect Password:=PW
            If Len(.Value2) > 0 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Offset(, -1) = Now
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
            .Locked = True
            .Worksheet.Protect Password:=PW
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello.  Thank you for your help.  This worked perfectly.